# Button do not work jsf

Tags: jsf

I have an .xhtml page. Button do not work.

```
  <div class="overlay-inner" id="overlay-inner">
        <h:button onclick="toggle()" value="Overlay" id="toggleButton"/>
    </div>
```

and css file

```
.overlay-inner{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url(../resources/img/28h3fwh.png) repeat;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
.overlay-inner input{
    z-index:51;
    color: #000;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

and js function

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function(){
                if ( $("#overlay-inner").css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
                     $("#overlay-inner").css('visibility','visible');
                  else
                     $("#overlay-inner").css('visibility','hidden');
                });
```

when i'm pressing button, nothing happend.

Comment: try setting the action property of a button

Comment: try this $("#form\\:toggleButton").click(function()) on your java script where form is <h:form> id.

Comment: `"toggleButton"` is not a valid CSS selector. To select an element by ID, you need to prefix it with `#`. This has completely nothing to with JSF.

Comment: @BalusC sorry my mistake.